# How to get the compiler to say what type it thinks an expression is?

Tags: kotlin, types, type-inference, diagnostics

Is there a way to get the Kotlin compiler to tell me exactly what type it thinks an expression is? So e.g. given `(1 + 2)` it would print `Int`.

Better example: `(if (args.isEmpty()) 1 else 2.0)` should print Any, because that's what the compiler thinks is the type of that term, because the best it can do at compile time is infer the most specific supertype of `Int` and `Double`.

Comment: Something like `(1+2).javaClass.simpleName`?

Comment: @MadhuBhat That shows what the type ends up being at runtime, but what the compiler thinks the type is, might be different. Better example: `(if (args.isEmpty()) 1 else 2.0)`

Comment: What should be printed for your example and why do you need that?

Comment: Would be better to elaborate on your question with specifics of what you need with more context. It seems vague the way it is currently.

Comment: @IR42 Added better example with result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun main() {
    println(typeName { if (true) 1 else 2.5 }) // Any
    println(typeName { 1 + 2 }) // Int
    println(typeName { f() }) // String
}


fun f(): String = TODO() // throws NotImplementedError

inline fun <reified T> typeName(block: () -> T): String? = T::class.simpleName
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need this functionality while you're editing your code, IntelliJ based IDEs support this. The action is called *Type Info*, and you can access it with <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd> (<kbd>⌃⇧P</kbd> on macOS) by default.

[image: Example of using Type Info]